# without infinitive

Tags: infinitives

I am wondering why there is no infinitive before the word plan in the sentences below.

- Thanks for helping me plan this out.

Is it the same rule with the words make and let? Or, it is about other rules? Let me know it, please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the "primary" verb ***help*** that matters here, not the specific "secondary" verb *(plan, work,...)* in the subordinate clause. But usage changes over time - with ***make*** as the primary verb, we don't normally include the "infinitive marker" ***to***, so it's *He made me do it*, today. But long, long ago, it was *He **maketh me TO lie down** in green pastures*.

Comment: "Plan this out" **is** an infinitival clause. The catenative verb "help" takes a _to_-infinitival or a bare infinitival complement. In other words, the "to" is optional here.